# Magento remarketing tag

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, google-analytics, parameter, google-tag-manager

I have a magento remarketing tag but I can not configure it correctly. I have the following parameters:

```
var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
ecomm_pagetype: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
ecomm_totalvalue: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
dynx_itemid: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
dynx_itemid2: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
dynx_pagetype: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
dynx_totalvalue: 'REPLACE_WITH_VALUE',
};
```

This returns me the following errors:

```
Number field should not be quoted: 'ecomm_totalvalue'
Number field should not be quoted: 'dynx_totalvalue'
```

**Code used:**

```
(function(){
 try {
    url_atual = $j('#urlAtual').val();
    alert(url_atual);
  if(url_atual == "catalog"){
   var prodid, totalvalue;
   //page product/category
   totalvalue = $j('#valor_produto').val();
   prodid = $j('#id_produto').val();
   alert(totalvalue);
   alert(prodid);
   dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'fireRemarketingTag',
    google_tag_params: {
      'ecomm_prodid': prodid,
      'ecomm_pagetype': 'product',
      ecomm_totalvalue: totalvalue
    }
   });
  }
  else if (url_atual == "ajax") {
   var prodid, totalvalue;
  //cart
   console.log('entrou carrinho');
   dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'fireRemarketingTag',
    'google_tag_params': {
      'ecomm_prodid': prodid,
      'ecomm_pagetype': 'cart',
      'ecomm_totalvalue': totalvalue
    }
   });
  }
  else if (url_atual == "cms") {
   var prodid, totalvalue;
   //other pages/cms
   dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'fireRemarketingTag',
    'google_tag_params': {
      'ecomm_prodid': prodid,
      'ecomm_pagetype': 'purchase',
      'ecomm_totalvalue': totalvalue
    }
   });
  }
  else {
   dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'fireRemarketingTag',
    'google_tag_params': { }
   });
  }
 }
 catch (err) {}
}) ();
```

I have already tried setting up data layers but with no success. And after a lot of searching too, I did not find anything that could help me do the same setup on magento. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the snippet that you use to assign the data to `ecomm_totalvalue` and `dynx_totalvalue` as the error messages states that you have the passed values quoted (i.e. `ecomm_totalvalue: '100.00'` does not work, where else `ecomm_totalvalue: 100.00` does).

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner I updated the question with the code used.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/sreichel/magento-Anaraky-GDRT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another solution based on the discussion in the comments you may be want to place something like this in your Minicart template (`app/design/frontend/[theme]/[theme]/template/checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml`).

*Please note, that this snippet never really got optimized nor revised as it was a quick fix in a particular situation some long time ago.*

```
<!-- REMARKETING -->
<?php $conversionId = "YOUR CONVERSION ID"; // place your conversion id here ?>
<?php 
    $routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); 
    $identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
    $productReg = Mage::registry('current_product');
    $categoryReg = Mage::registry('current_category');

    $ecomm_category = null;
    $ecomm_prodid = null;

    if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName() === 'checkout_onepage_success'):
        $ecomm_pagetype = 'purchase';
        $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item):
            $itemIds[] = "'".$item->getSku()."'";
        endforeach;
        $ecomm_prodid = "[".implode(",", $itemIds)."]";

    elseif($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home'):
        $ecomm_pagetype = 'home';
        $ecomm_prodid = null;

    elseif($routeName == 'checkout'):
        $ecomm_pagetype = 'cart';

        $itemIds = array();
        $quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        if($quote->getItemsCount()):
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item):
                $itemIds[] = "'".$item->getSku()."'";
            endforeach;
        $ecomm_prodid = "[".implode(",", $itemIds)."]";
        else:
            $ecomm_prodid = null;
        endif;

    elseif($routeName == 'catalogsearch'):
        $ecomm_pagetype = 'searchresults';
        $ecomm_prodid = null;

    elseif($routeName == 'catalog'):
        if($categoryReg):
            $ecomm_category = $categoryReg->getName();
        endif;
        if($productReg):
            $ecomm_pagetype = 'product';
            $ecomm_prodid = "'".$productReg->getSku()."'";
        else:
            $ecomm_pagetype = 'category';
            $ecomm_prodid = null;
        endif;

    else:
        $ecomm_pagetype = 'other';
        $ecomm_prodid = null;
    endif;


    if($ecomm_pagetype == 'purchase'):
        $ecomm_totalvalue = $order->getGrandTotal();
    elseif($ecomm_pagetype == 'cart'):
        $ecomm_totalvalue = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        if($ecomm_totalvalue == null):
            $ecomm_totalvalue = 0;
        endif;
    elseif($ecomm_pagetype == 'product'):
        $ecomm_totalvalue = $productReg->getFinalPrice();
    else:
        $ecomm_totalvalue = null;
    endif;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var google_tag_params = {
        ecomm_pagetype: <?php echo "'".$ecomm_pagetype."'"; ?>,
        <?php if($ecomm_prodid != null): ?>
            ecomm_prodid: <?php echo $ecomm_prodid; ?>,
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($ecomm_category != null): ?>
            ecomm_category: <?php echo "'".$ecomm_category."'"; ?>,
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($ecomm_totalvalue != null): ?>
            ecomm_totalvalue: <?php echo $ecomm_totalvalue; ?>,
        <?php endif; ?>
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = <?php echo $conversionId; ?>;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/<?php echo $conversionId; ?>/?guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

---

Even if `alert(totalvalue);` for example would return `100` it most likey is still just a string rather than a number. You can check that by `alert(typeof(totalvalue)); // expected result in this case is 'string'`.

So you will have to convert that *string* to a *number* using something like `totalvalue = Number($j('#valor_produto').val());` or `'ecomm_totalvalue': Number(totalvalue)`. If you now `alert(typeof(totalvalue));` you should get prompted `number`.

So, for example:

```
(function(){
 try {
    url_atual = $j('#urlAtual').val();
    alert(url_atual);
  if(url_atual == "catalog"){
   var prodid, totalvalue;
   //page product/category
   totalvalue = Number($j('#valor_produto').val()); // forcing type "number" rather than default "string"
   prodid = $j('#id_produto').val();
   alert(totalvalue);
   alert(prodid);
   dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'fireRemarketingTag',
    google_tag_params: {
      'ecomm_prodid': prodid,
      'ecomm_pagetype': 'product',
      'ecomm_totalvalue': totalvalue // added missing quotes
    }
   });
  }
  else if (url_atual == "ajax") {
   var prodid, totalvalue;
  //cart
   console.log('entrou carrinho');
   dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'fireRemarketingTag',
    'google_tag_params': {
      'ecomm_prodid': prodid,
      'ecomm_pagetype': 'cart',
      'ecomm_totalvalue': totalvalue
    }
   });
  }
  else if (url_atual == "cms") {
   var prodid, totalvalue;
   //other pages/cms
   dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'fireRemarketingTag',
    'google_tag_params': {
      'ecomm_prodid': prodid,
      'ecomm_pagetype': 'purchase',
      'ecomm_totalvalue': totalvalue
    }
   });
  }
  else {
   dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'fireRemarketingTag',
    'google_tag_params': { }
   });
  }
 }
 catch (err) {}
}) ();
```

---

**For easy debugging:**

One easy way to test google-snippet integrations is using the `Tag Assistant (by Google)` Google Chrome extension ([Tag Assistant on chrome.google.com](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk)).

**General tag type definitions for Google Remarketing:**

Example for retailers (more types linked in the source):

```
Custom parameter    Sample values   Definition
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ecomm_prodid*       1234            The product ID parameter allows your dynamic ads to show people the exact product they viewed on your website.
ecomm_pagetype**    home,           The page type parameter collects which pages people visited on your website.
                    searchresults, 
                    category,       To use automatically created lists, this value must be in English, even if your site is in a different language.
                    product, 
                    cart, purchase, 
                    other
ecomm_totalvalue**  49.99           The total product value parameter is the value of the product. On cart pages with multiple products, total product value is the sum of all items someone has selected.


*Required
**Recommended
```

Source: [AdWords Help on support.google.com](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7305793?hl=en&ref_topic=3180758)

Comment: But how would that look in code suits? Because that's what I'm having trouble with. And this error that I put in the question comes precisely from that extension of google chrome.

Comment: @MatheusPortela - added the snippet to this post. If it does not work try alerting the type of the var totalvalue (i.e. `alert(typeof(totalvalue));`)

Comment: It did not work, it still continues to give the error in chrome extension.

Comment: what's the content of `google_tag_params`? You can check that in that Chrome extension or when you inspect the source of the page.

Comment: Of the following contents: Number field should not be quoted: 'ecomm_totalvalue' and Number field should not be quoted: 'dynx_totalvalue'

Comment: no, what are the actual param's values?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: What do you see here? https://www.screencast.com/t/zflw2mfJiz - does `ecomm_totalvalue` still contain quotes?

Comment: In this field, `ecomm_totalvalue` I get the value: `REPLACE_WITH_VALUE`

Comment: @MatheusPortela - `REPLACE_WITH_VALUE` is just a placeholder. Then what is the other code you've posted? I thought you're polluting the vals with the same? However, is it necessarily a jQuery you need to use? Else I got some  PHP snippet which you could put into your minicart template in order to achieve the same...

Comment: So, the code of the script I put in a common file from which it is displayed on all pages, then those values ​​should be taken dynamically. I tested the `php` code that you put in your answer and it worked, but with the caches turned on, it ends up caching the `php` outputs. In case I should put this code in a `controller` and make an `ajax` request so I can not cache this code, and how should I proceed to assign those values ​​that will be returned to google's parameter variables? Was it through a datalayer?

Comment: Placed it in the minicart? Since this shouldn't be cached (works for me with Magento default caches enabled - are you using some Full Page cache extension?). What do you mean exactly by "it ends up caching the php outputs."?

Comment: No, in case he is not in the minicart. It is in a footer that is standard on every page and yes, I am using a full page cache module. What I mean is that for example, I entered the home page and the variable `$ ecomm_pagetype` gets the value `home`. Because of the cache, if I enter another page, even if the product is for example, my output from `php`, or in case the value, will always be home independent of the page that I am.

Comment: You can't place this snippet in the footer when you use full page cache unless you define exceptions (in case if this is even possible for a particular area of the footer, which I doubt - that's why the minicart). Note: Google itself would suggest to place it in the header rather than in the footer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71742/discussion-between-matheus-portela-and-christoph-farnleitner).